# How to restrain input to options/strings?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
private void txtS_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Also have a class for this:

```
public string S = ""
```

Which is connected to a Form input made by the user but I want to make him only able to input the following strings/conditions:

"Old" or "New"

If you need more info let me know,
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use regex to determine whether what's entered is other string or anything else

Comment: Sounds like a job for the amazing ***ComboBox***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't quite understand the question. Do you want the user to send you string input with value "Old" or "New"?

If so, you can either use combobox to make sure you'll get the value you want(as long as something were selected, or to use regex(after successful convertion the input to string), or simply check manually:

```
if(s!= "Old" && s!= "New" )
//send error messeage
```

Comment: I want to force the user to only be able to input: "Old" or "New"

Comment: it shoud be contained on the class I specified above

Comment: I see. are you using mvvm?

Comment: And one more thing, can you add your code that connect the class to a the Form input ?

Comment: No to mvvm and yes to the 2nd question

Comment: As I said then, either use combobox(don't forget to check that something was selected or put something like this in the txtS_TextChanged function :
if(s!= "Old" && s!= "New" )
{
txtS.Text = String.Empy; // remove the invalid input
return; //Exit the function
}

Comment: I got this error Invalid token 'if' in class, struct, or interface member declaration  also for the "!=" expression

Comment: Are you comparing 2 strings or trying to compare string to someting else? 
Edit your question please and write your code.